# Auto rotate doesn't work after setRequestedOrientation when button is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-layout, autorotate

I have this video view. It has a fullscreen button as a controller. The auto rotation works normally at first, but whenever the fullscreen button is clicked, the screen rotate to be landscape, and when I try to auto rotate, it doesn't auto rotate to portrait.

Here is a screenshot of my video view and controller.

[image]
Here is my code for fullscreen button onClickEvent

```
mFullScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                //To fullscreen
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                mFullScreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.fullscreen);
                toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                updateMetadata(false);

            } else {

                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                getSupportActionBar().hide();
                mFullScreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal_screen);
                toolbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                updateMetadata(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is my onConfiguration changed method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    getSupportActionBar().show();
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        try {
            channelNameText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            channelImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
            ne.printStackTrace();
        }

        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
        }
        updateMetadata(false);

    } else {

        Logger.e("Orientation", "ORIENTATION_POTRAIT");

        try {
            channelNameText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            channelImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
            ne.printStackTrace();
        }

        mFullScreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.fullscreen);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
        }
        updateMetadata(true);
    }
}
```

The onConfiguration method is called but only when we press the fullscreen button. How do I enable auto rotation after setRequestedOrientation?

Comment: did you check if your auto rotation is on from the device ?

Comment: yes auto rotation is on and at first auto rotation works but after pressing fullscreen, which calls setRequestOrientation() the auto rotation doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change your activity’s orientation mode at any time as per your requirement, then below is the java code for doing the same. As we discuss all the Android screen orientation modes above, we can set any of the mode at any time from the java code. Below is the example for both landscape and portrait mode. But you can set all available modes as the same way. put the below lines of code anywhere in your activity java file, where you want to change the screen orientation of your activity. For example if want to set a particular orientation before showing the screen, then you can add the code in onCreate() function of your activity.

For Landscape mode

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

For Portrait Mode

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

> Note: While adding this code, don’t forget to import the package
>   `import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;` in to your code.

Sometime, you want to get the screen orientation of the current screen programmatically at runtime . To get the same you can try the below java code in your activity.java file.

```
//Get current screen orientation
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int orientation = display.getOrientation(); 
         switch(orientation) {
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
                setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                break;
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
                setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                break;                  
        }
```

Note: Don’t forget to import below packages for the above code.

```
import android.view.Display;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.view.WindowManager;
```